# how to measure the instruction count during execution?

Tags: c#, .net, profiler

I want to mesure how much instruction are executed in method example.

```
int a=0;
functionTest();
a=getCountInstruction() // return the number of instruction executed until now.
```

Their any way to do it using Profiler or some Classes ?

Comment: Refer to [Parsing the IL of a Method Body](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14058/Parsing-the-IL-of-a-Method-Body)

Comment: This question has been marked as duplicate but that was the state of play 6 years ago and times change. If I had to do this now I would use a profiler similar to OpenCover (code coverage) - you can measure how many sequence points you hit and therefore infer how may IL instructions were therefore executed for each sequence point... but there is nothing out of the box...

Answer (score 0):

You have to add increase counter when you invoke your method

```
static int a=0;
functionTest()
{
    a++;
    //your code
}
```

Comment: it's will calculate the functiontest() as one instruction and it contained lot of insctruction which is wrong but i mean with instruction process instruction, because contrunction is not same like declaration or calling method

Comment: I think you want to profile your application, so read some information about CPU profiling in Visual Studio

Comment: There you have some information http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/profiling-application-visual.

Comment: i need it by coding not using external application :) if their a way it will be so helpfull

Comment: Why do you need it in code? If you explain it for me, I will be easier for me to help you